# Facing problem while importing project into the workspace

Tags: android

I had  the same issue before and tried many ways to slove it. Now it is working fine with importing project. Now am facing some  related issue that is, there are some apiDemos in the plugin with my friend. I have copied it and tried to import it into the workspace but here is the same problem again showing that it has some or the other error in every line.

And this is the screen shot of how the error look in every line. Can anyone help in this case.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: right click on project >> property>> click on android >> show project build taget

Comment: in this targetName are checked or not?

Comment: yes,it is there checked with android2.2

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uJWD1.png

Comment: i think there are library are missing

Comment: please update screen shot with package explorer

Comment: please clean your project and tell me what happen

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are adding the same project in the workspace which is already there..
As you have mentioned the sample code of `APIdemos` .Make sure you are not duplicating the project in the workspace as you will not be able to import it..If any other error comes please specify a little more...

Answer (score 1):

**take precaution while you import project**

- Check whether same name project are not exist in work space
- copy and past in your workspace
- goto property and check that taget are checked or not?
- ckeck manifest file that all activity are define?
- check that import project have use any external library?
- and if use then library are existing or not?

Answer (score 0):

When you have the Eclipse for j2ee installed, clicking run when editing a layout xml doens't run your project but rather create a new file called, for example, main.out.xml, which is what I see in your error at the bottom of your screenshot.
This file doesn't let the project be built until you delete it since the Android build process checks all xml files and uses them and this file shouldn't be there.
Find this file, delete it, and run the project by right clicking the name of the project and clicking run as -> Android application

Comment: sorry, i understood that you want me to delete some file from the project. But did not understood which file is to be deleted. Can u please illustrate me that again. thanks for the response

Comment: main.out.xml and possibly other xml files with .out. in their name

Answer (score 0):

The error that is coming is not your fault.
Its the eclipse that is not working..
your R.java file is not updating when you are importing the project. That is the reason because of which the code for Activity, View, Bundle, Animation is showing error. Updating your R.java file manually will solve the error.

And the @override indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a superclass.

This annotation is useful for compile-time checking to verify that the method you're overriding is valid (overridden correctly).

but as the superclass Activity is having error as the org.eclipse has not loaded and R.java is not updated thus the error is coming. as soon as you update the file, all the error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

1)Check if project exist in the workspace.
2)Clean project in your workspace.
3)Right click on the project,select Android > Project Build Target(select 1)>select is library> Apply.
4)Ensure external jars correctly imported!

This worked for me buddie